# UISegmentControl inside smaller UIView to hide borders, keeps expanding it

Tags: ios, autolayout, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to put a `SegmentControl` inside of a slightly smaller `UIView` in order to clip the Segment control just enough to hide the 1px border and corner rounding.

Using the auto-layout parameters below on by `SegmentControl`, I put it inside a device width `UIView` with the height of 37px.  The goal is that the `segmentControl` is 2px larger on all the boundaries, and is clipped.

This works well, usually.  The problem is not always.  For some reason on certain `ViewControllers` when it is all the way on top, the bottom of the `SegmentControl` refuses to hide and I see the bottom border line.

On another when it is in the center of the page vertically, I am always seeing the top border.  I even try making the segment control super large, and change the -2's, to -10s, and the segment control appears larger.

The main problem is that the outer UIView does not seem to be enforcing its height equals constraint, and thus gets larger.  I've tried turning off as many "AutoResize Subview"s as I can test, but this does not seem to change it.  I use `ClipSubviews` on the parent View also.

Any suggestions on how I can make this height constraint rock-hard unchangeable to the View, and really get this to stick?

[image]

Comment: You can set background image for your UISegmentedControl to hide borders.

Comment: Are you testing in simulator? If so can you check with 100% scale to see exactly what's happening and add some snapshots?

Comment: Have you set UIView's 'clipSubviews' to 'true' ?